# How to save values in a list in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a Form in a Partial View which the code is :

```
<%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProfileGa")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems)%>

        </div>
        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%>
         </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
          <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nbr_Passage)%>
          </div>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Position)%>
        </div>


        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "dd" })%>

        </div>


        <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  />
        </div>

        </fieldset>
```

and this is how it looks :
[image: pic]
I want to save the values entred in a List. So I created a list in my view model like this :

```
public List<Gamme> ListG = new List<Gamme>();
```

Then in my Controller 'ProfileGaController', I defined a method save to save in the list :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Gamme G = new Gamme();
            G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
            G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;

            G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
            G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
            G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);
            model.ListG.Add(G);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");    
    }
```

***Problem :***

Each time I a save in the list, th values are deleted and replaced by new ones.

Always, I have count=1 for the list :

[image: pp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this list at all. The `Model` only exists for the duration of this controller action, and you're not passing it on to the view. In your code, you're making a new `Gamme`, adding it to a list, and then throwing the whole thing away. If you're just trying to save a new `Gamme` in the database, does it not work if you do

```
db.Gammes.Add(G);
db.SaveChanges();
```

instead of

```
model.ListG.Add(G);
```

What's the purpose of the list?

Edited after further clarification:

It seems like you want a temporary list of `Gamme` items added in one session, so you can use a session variable to store a list of Gammes you've added at that time. Initialise in the controller and add in the save action like so:

```
((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]).Add(G);
```

Then if you want to assign it to a parameter of the View Model it's like:

```
model.ListG = (List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"];
```

I, personally, would go back and engineer this slightly differently. I would put a `bool` on `Gamme` called "processed" or something similar, and when you create them, set it to `false`. That way, instead of using a session variable list, you can get the same list by selecting all `Gamme` objects where processed is false.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that s was my first approach : To save directly in the base and I did it with success but Now they recommend me to save first in a list because I need to do some Tests operations before the record

Comment: What do you need to test? Just the new Gamme, or the list of all Gammes including the new one.

Comment: List of New Gammes but each one depends on the others

Comment: You're only creating one new one at a time though, where is the rest of the list coming from?

Comment: At the beginning the list is empty then on each click , I add new Gamme. At the end, I test dependences between them and if it Ok , I record all the list in the Base.

Answer (score 1):

You will always have 1 in the list, because you are creating a new instance of ListG with new List(); So when this is passed back to the controller, it will be newed up and you will add your new G object resulting in a count of 1. Alternatively you could try this: (assuming your db instance is locally accessible)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Gamme G = new Gamme();
        G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
        G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;

        G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
        G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
        G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);
        model.ListG = db.Gammes.ToList();
        model.ListG.Add(G);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the result is the same my friend !

Comment: How many Gammes are currently persisted in the DB? Also, have you tried changing your property on your view model to use a normal getter and setter: public List<Gamme> ListG { get; set; }

Comment: I tried ,,,that will be Null exception and about How many Gammes , i don t know if my answer is right but count of ListG became 6